# View files with Hyperlink ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a directory containing files (images , pdf ..etc).. then I've got all the directory files with c# code and viewed them as a hyperlink for each file to be able to view each file in the browser.
when I click on the pdf file link for example , it doesn't view the file .. but when I copy the link address of the pdf file , then paste and view it in a separated window . the pdf file open normally.
when I view the source code of the page I find that the link for the pdf file as it is in my local machine directory not the server one.

Please help me with that.. 
Thanks.

Comment: please show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a security issue. In console, you must be seeing the error "Not allowed to load local resource". On clicking the anchor tag, which contains the absolute path to local file, the file has to be served by the IIS server(as the page is web page, which is loaded from asp.net application), which is not allowed.

In a web application, if you provide local file path to a file in your webpages, you are making the assumption that the file exists on the clients computer or device and not on your server.

So, create a folder inside your applications root folder and just give relative path to those files in anchor tag that includes hostname like

http://myserver.com/aspnet.pdf